# mvn dependency for repository.save()

Tags: java, maven

I am struggling with this. I every time I add the main class in repository.save(CustomerDetails) I get an error message. When I click on error I asked to add a dependency but it doesn't tell me what dependency to add.

How do I figure out?

Here's my class:

```
package com.example.Customer.Application;

import com.example.Customer.CustomerRepository.CustomerDetailRepository;
import com.example.Customer.Model.CustomerDetails;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AccountApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private void name(CustomerDetailRepository repository) {
        List<CustomerDetails> cd = new ArrayList<>();
        cd.add(new CustomerDetails(1, "Foo", "Bar"));
        cd.add(new CustomerDetails(2, "Foo1", "Bar1"));


        CustomerDetails cdd = new CustomerDetails(1, "a", "b");
        {

        }

        repository.save(CustomerDetails); this is where the error is. 

    }

}
```

Here's my main class:

```
package com.example.Customer.Model;

import com.example.Customer.CustomerApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;


@Entity
public class CustomerDetails {


    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;


    public CustomerDetails() {

      }

    public CustomerDetails(long id, String name, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

here's my controller code

```
package com.example.Customer.Controller;

import com.example.Customer.Model.CustomerDetails;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.RETURN;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



@RestController
public class Customerapplication {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/findcustomer")
    public CustomerDetails createnewcustomerrecord() {

        return new CustomerDetails(1, "Sarah", "88 strong road");
    }

}
```

Can any help? Do you know what dependency I can add to fix this bug?

Comment: does this even compile" repository.save(CustomerDetails);" ? second why your "Repository"  is an inner class "CustomerRepository.CustomerDetailRepository" ? Try changeing "repository" name to  "customerDetailRepository" in "name" method .  try add "Inject" annotation on it too.

Comment: It does not compile. I changed my "repository" class   to import com.example.Customer.customerDetailRepository.CustomerDetailRepository; But some reason I still can't get it to work.

Comment: It's not what i meant.  Could You edit your question to show us Repository. Note:remember that packages in java should be lowercase (all words). But that's not the case.  Try (repository.save(cdd))